# What causes KSystemStats to run and consume many GB of RAM - how to prevent this?

Tags: debian, kde

I didn't configure anything related to it so why is it getting started every other day or so and take up lots of RAM (I think basically all free RAM if not killed via the process manager)?

It's occurring on the latest stable Debian 11 with KDE.

Comment: what does "consuming" mean in this context? a process can reserve and then not use a lot of RAM.

Comment: The process manager (KsysGuard) display that large and increasing number under "Memory". It takes up a lot of RAM, I don't know what it's doing and quit it every time it happens (I notice it every time because other things slow down).

Comment: As said, "memory" is ambiguous, and can mean many different things (it's not very useful that Ksysguard has an otherwise unlabeled column "Memory", not your fault!). But if other things slow down and run at normal speed after you end that process, then quite possibly, yes, your KSystemStats process is occupying a lot of resident memory. Maybe by design, maybe due to a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this KDE bug:

[ksystemstats memory leak](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441543)

Comment: `sudo apt purge ksysguard`. Kde plasma depends on it, but I'm running Xfce. Its work.